# DefaultCookieSerializer.setJvmRoute is not working

Tags: java, spring, redis, session-cookies, spring-session

I am trying to incorporate SpringSession into my application, but I also want to preserve server affinity as I have Talend jobs that require sticky sessions.

I can get the SpringSession with Redis working as desired, and to get the server  affinity working I want to append a jvmRoute to the session in the new Cookie.

In my Config file I create the following bean as per the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html

```
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
    serializer.setJvmRoute("my-app1");
    return serializer;
}
```

This renames the SESSION to JSESSIONID so I know it works, but it is not appending the jvmRoute to the sessionId.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at the actual session cookie value and hope to see the configured `jvmRoute` appended to it, keep in mind that starting with Spring Session 2.0 the `DefaultCookieSerializer` uses Base64 encoded cookies by default.

So the `jvmRoute` actually is appended to session id, but the entire concatenation gets Base64 encoded before it is written to the cookie.

In order to verify `jvmRoute`, you can try testing using `DefaultCookieSerializer` configured with `serializer.setUseBase64Encoding(false)`.

Comment: That was my issue. so I did exactly as you said and it worked. However, I'm now running into another issue, which I have asked about here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868693/springsession-defaultcookieserializer-setjvmroute-works-but-httpservletrequest

Comment: I've posted the answer to your other question. Since you didn't accept this answer, is there anything left here that needs further explanation?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to accept the answer. Thanks very much