# SpringSession DefaultCookieSerializer.setJvmRoute works, but HttpServletRequest does not have the jvmRoute required

Tags: java, servlets, redis, session-cookies, spring-session

I have implemented Spring Session with `Redis` in my legacy Spring MVC application. I also used the `DefaultCookieSerializer` to set the `jvmRoute`, because I need some server affinity for Talend jobs to be able to run.

When I run the front end and inspect the page in Chrome, I see the `jvmRoute` appended to the session. If I edit this from "node1" to "node2", the session is preserved. If I redeploy the server and make requests during that deployment, I get redirected to another node in the cluster, which means that Spring Sessions is working perfect.

However, I cannot get server affinity because when I debug a `HttpServletRequest` as it comes into my Spring app, the `HttpServletRequest.getSession().getId()` doesn't have the `jvmRoute` in it (although the hex number matches what I see in Chrome), and this is what I pass to the Talend job.

If I revert back to Tomcat session and set the `jvmRoute` in the Engine component of `server.xml`, I see the `jvmRoute` appended to the session id in both Chrome and when debugging the code.

What exactly does the `DefaultCookieSerializer` do? I thought it edits the cookie as it is being created, and that is how the cookie is to be stored in `Redis`. So any use of this cookie subsequent to being created should have the `jmvRoute` attached if you set it up that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly does the DefaultCookieSerializer do? I thought it edits the cookie as it is being created, and that is how the cookie is to be stored in Redis. So any use of this cookie subsequent to being created should have the jmvRoute attached if you set it up that way.

First, it's important to realize the cookie itself isn't stored in session store (i.e. Redis in your case). What's stored is the representation of session itself, along with its attributes.

Besides session storage, other important aspect of session management is the correlation of user's HTTP request with the stored session. With Spring Session's Servlet API support this is the responsibility of `HttpSessionIdResolver`, and by default Spring Session uses cookie based implementation i.e. `CookieHttpSessionIdResolver`. There's also an HTTP header based implementation in `HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver`. I'm stating this because it's important to realize that session storage are distinct concerns that operate on different levels.

Now, regarding the `CookieHttpSessionIdResolver`, it delegates cookie writing and reading concerns to `CookieSerializer` (with `DefaultCookieSerializer` being the... well, default implementation). According to its configuration, `DefaultCookieSerializer` will respect a number of options when writing and reading session cookies i.e. cookie name, whether to Base64 encode cookie value, whether to use `httpOnly` cookie directive etc.

> However, I cannot get server affinity because when I debug a HttpServletRequest as it comes into my Spring app, the HttpServletRequest.getSession().getId() doesn't have the jvmRoute in it (although the hex number matches what I see in Chrome), and this is what I pass to the Talend job.

This is the part that I don't understand - if you're able to resolve `HttpSession` from the current `HttpServletRequest` then you know what `jvmRoute` it's bound to right? It's the `jvmRoute` of the current JVM, otherwise session wouldn't be resolved `HttpServletRequest` in handled by this JVM.

What's different between the Spring Session and Tomcat's session management, is that with Tomcat the `jvmRoute` is [session id generation related concern](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html) while with Spring Session the `jvmRoute` is used in the context of session cookie serialization.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the reason I want the jvmRoute appended to the session, is that I pass that as a string to Talend (using scripts), this jvmRoute is used my talend to make more calls to my application. I need the server affinity because there are some generated files stored locally.

Comment: Is there a specific filter that I can debug that strips the route off the sessionId? I think this is what must be happening because why would the client have it and the server not?

Comment: In otherwords, in Spring, at what point does the HttpSession get set with the sessionId from the cookie and can I prevent the pruning of jvmRoute from happening?

Comment: I tried to explain in the answer that with Spring Session `jvmRoute` is a cookie serialization aspect - so the logic that takes the configured `jvmRoute` into account is a part of `DefaultCookieSerializer`. But again, if you've resolved session from the current request, you know what `jvmRoute` it's bound to - current JVM. You can then simply append it to session id yourself before passing it to downstream app. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I completely understand you. I can determine the JvmRoute anywhere in the code from the hostname. However, the sessionId that I pass to Talend is quiet a complex string where the HttpSession identifier is only part of it. This now means I have to split the string, insert my jvmRoute and reassemble the identifier. Not a big deal, it's only a few lines of code. However, we intend on removing sticky sessions from our application in the next year, so I was hoping to not have to revisit that part of the code again. I've opened a ticket with Spring to see if they would implement what I wanted.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-860 Is the Spring ticket. Thanks for your feedback, I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: As this is Spring Session concern, you should open the ticket in [Spring Session issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues), not Spring Data Redis. Feel free to include link to this question.